# c-function fprintf variable file pointer

Tags: c, file, pointers, printf

I have multiple file pointers. During a loop I want to print something into a certain file. Which file depends on the loop pass.

```
fprintf(stream,"v   t \n");
```

With "stream" I choose the file. Is it possible to pass a certain array element as stream?

For example:

```
FILE *vx;
FILE *vy;
FILE *vz;

vx=fopen("vx.txt","w");
vy=fopen("vy.txt","w"); 
vz=fopen("vz.txt","w");

pointer[]={vx,vy,vz};

while(n<4)
{
    funck(n, k, v, w, h);
    fprintf(pointer[n-1],"v t \n");
    n+=1;
}
```

Is it a possible to save file pointer in an array? Is this a good solution?

Comment: Arrays (both fixed-size and dynamically allocated) of pointers are very common, just look at the `main` function arguments to find one.

Comment: But what data type should the array have?

Comment: `FILE *pointer[] = {vx, vy, vz};` or `FILE *pointer[3]; pointer[0] = vx; pointer[1] = vy; pointer[2] = vz;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, as long as you pass a variable of type `FILE *` to `fprintf()`.

The array type must be of type `FILE*`, since the array store pointers to a referenced `FILE` object (`FILE*`).

If you were using pointers, the pointer's type must have been be `FILE**`, since it's a pointer(`*`) to a referenced `FILE` object (`FILE*`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Type your array with FILE *.